# Order of $x^{1/x}-1$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Order of $x^{1/x}-1$ as $x \to \infty$

Answer been given: $x^{1/x}-1=O(\frac{\ln x}{x})$

My attempt is to expand the equation:
$x^{1/x}=exp(\frac{\ln x}{x})$

I am unable to proceed further, any ideas?

Comment: Use that $\log(x)/x \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ and following from this, u can safely taylor expand the exponential

Comment: slightly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622318/calculating-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-sqrtnn-1

Comment: tired you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 2):

As said in tired's comment:

$x^{1/x}-1=exp(\frac{\ln x}{x})-1=1+\frac{\ln x}{x}+(\frac{\ln x}{x})^2/2+...-1=\frac{\ln x}{x}+(\frac{\ln x}{x})^2/2+...=O(\frac{\ln x}{x})$

Comment: Well done! :) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

As $\mathrm e^u=1+u+o(u)$, we have
$$x^{\tfrac1x}=1+\frac{\ln x}x+o\Bigl(\frac{\ln x}x\Bigr),\quad\text{whence}\quad x^{\tfrac1x}-1=\frac{\ln x}x+o\Bigl(\frac{\ln x}x\Bigr),$$
which proves $x^{\tfrac1x}-1\sim_\infty\dfrac{\ln x}x$, *a fortiori*  $\;\;x^{\tfrac1x}-1=O\Bigl(\dfrac{\ln x}x\Bigr).$